# toggle classname according to click

Tags: reactjs

[image]
I want to toggle active classname to particular month clicked and january should be bydefault active and these months are mapping from array

```
<div className="first6-months"> {Data[5].firstsixmonths.map((item, key) => ( <p className={item === "January" ? "jan" : "feb"} // onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, key)} > {item} </p> ))} </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set an "active" class to the selected item that how I would do it:

```
const [months, setMonths] = useState('January')

const handleChange = (event) => {
   setMonths(event.target.name)
}

return (
<div className="first6-months"> 
   {Data[5].firstsixmonths.map((item, key) => ( 
        <p className={item === month ? "active" : ""}
           onClick={handleChange}
           name={item}> 
         {item} 
         </p> 
    ))} 
</div>
)
```

Comment: if february is clicked than january should be normal and february should be now active

Comment: Yea, that will work, if any month is clicked, it will  be activated and the rest desactivated

Comment: it is not working

Comment: Please add `key` attribute in `p` tag inside .map function loop

Answer (score 0):

1. When looping output, always put a `key` prop on your element

```js
{Data[5].firstsixmonths.map((item, key) => ( <p key={item} onClick={() => handleClick(key)} > {item} </p> ))}
```

2. Use some bit of state to track which month is active

```js
const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(0);
const handleClick = (key) = setActiveItem(key);
```

3. Then set your `className` based upon `active`

```js
import classnames from `classnames`;
//...
<p className={classnames({
  active: item === Data[5].firstsixmonths[activeItem]
})} onClick={() => handleClick(key)}>{item}</p>
```

This is the basics of what you need, but you'll probably need to play with it a little.

Comment: You only want one 'active' class for your buttons

Comment: it is solved thank you